# Using expression on document value in filter | PHP MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to find all the documents in my mongodb collection that are from the specified range of dates. All of this in php but the problem is that Date field is a string.

I have documents in my collection in mongodb which look like this:

```
{
  "Number": "12345",
  "Date": "Tue, 06 Apr 93 12:03:11 GMT",
}
```

Now i have a problem to make a query in php that will return all records from date start_date and end_date. Here's my current solution which doesn't work:

```
$start_date = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($_GET['datep']) * 1000);
$end_date = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($_GET['datek']) * 1000);

$filter = [
    'Newsgroups' => ['$regex' => ".*".$_GET['group'].".*"],
    '$and' => [
        [ '$expr' => [ '$gte' => [ '$dateFromString' => [ 'dateString' => '$Date'] , $start_date ] ] ],
        [ '$expr' => [ '$lte' => [ '$dateFromString' => [ 'dateString' => '$Date'] , $end_date ] ] ],
    ],
]; 
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, []);
$cursor = $connection->executeQuery('newscol.news',$query);
```

It basically returns an error like:
An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$Date" }, 0: new Date(733968000000) }

Comment: So many questions about dates and databases start because someone is storing a date as a string. You should fix that. Your attempt to convert a string to a date is failing because MongoDB doesn't understand the date string, and you're not giving it any help. Add a date format string. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: i tried this solution but it turns out that not all dates are of the correct format in my collection. They can be formatted in php but don't work properly in mongodb command. For now I just added another field to my documents so now i have DateString and Date. Thanks for help